# Should I set a page as "No-index" if I include it's content within the front-Page.php via this method?

Tags: php, theme-development, filters, google-search, noindex

So I set my home page to "Your latest posts", and included this bit of code to get the info from a pre-defined page so that I can edit my home page, and get access to a "recent posts" grid with pagination at the same time. In addition, I can edit this post via the Gutenberg Block editor with this method.

I'd like to eliminate the possibility of a  "duplicate content" flag on my content, so should I no-index the source page?

```
<picture class="featured-image block  pos-rel">
    <div class="t-con flex row pos-abs">
        <h1  class="post-title f-center" title="<?php echo get_the_title( $ID=2 ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $ID=2 ); ?></h1> <!--Edit these values to adjust page being shown.-->
    </div>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 
        'class' => 'featured'
    )); ?>
</picture>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
<section class="main bg-darkpurple">
<?php 
    $id=2; 
    $post = get_post($id); 
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
    echo $content;  
?>
```

Also, I'm aware that the `the_title_attribute()` should be used in place of `echo get_the_title($ID=2)` however, when I use that, even with $ID declared, It outputs the attribute of the latest post instead.

Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than just no-indexing the Page, 301 redirect it. This can be done either by server config (.htaccess, NGINX rules, etc.) or using a plugin. That way no one can actually get to the Page all on its own - it only exists on the front page.

Comment: That is a much better option. I was thinking the sitemap that is autogenerated by yoast might cause some issues, but I suppose not. Thanks!

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to also exclude it from the Yoast sitemap, which your original noindex plan should also accomplish. Removing all traces of it as a separate page is ideal.